# Creating duplicate observations to compare as variables in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a database with different products per city. They are listed as single observations. Instead, I want it to be like an observation that compares two products in different cities. 
My actual database looks as follows:

```
Date Product Market Price  
 A      X       H     10
 A      X       I     5
 A      X       J     7
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Date Product Market1 Market2 Price1 Price2
 A      X       H       I      10     5
 A      X       H       J      10     7     
 A      X       I       J       5     7
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you all the way there. The basic idea is form all pairwise combinations within groups with `joinby` on an almost identical copy of the data, and then drop self matches and duplicates.

```
clear

input str1(Date Product Market) byte(Price)  
A X H 10
A X I 5
A X J 7
end

rename (Market Price) =2
tempfile markets
save "`markets'"
rename *2 *1
joinby Date Product using "`markets'"
drop if Market1>=Market2 // drop duplicates
order Date Product Market1 Market2 Price1 Price2
drop if Market1==Market2
list
```

Comment: To remove duplicates, why not simply write `drop if Market1>=Market2` instead of `drop if Market1==Market2`?

Comment: @eoraptor That is a much better way. Edited.